# Only one of my GPT drives is recognized by the BIOS

Tags: bios, uefi, gpt

I have two GPT drives, an SSD and an HDD.  My SSD has windows installed, my other HDD does not.  My problem is that my BIOS only shows the SSD in boot options, and ignores the HDD.  When the SSD is unplugged however, my HDD shows up.  I have a Gateway DX4860-ub33p.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Normally both the hard disk will show. Please check whether the secondary sata port/cable that you are adding hdd is working is working as it should be.

Comment: I've switched out both the port and cable, to no avail

Comment: When you only have the HDD plugged in, is it still plugged into the same SATA port? I have had MOBO that need you to specify what SATA ports are active or not. Try booting with both then try only unplugging the SSD and leaving the HDD on that SATA port and see if it recognizes it then. If not you have a bad SATA port or your that port on the MOBO is not activated.

Comment: The bios registers the HDD as plugged into a data slot, it's just not bootable from boot options

Comment: what SATA is it plugged into though?

Comment: It doesn't matter, I've plugged it into every port and it still doesn't make a difference.  The drive used to boot when it was MBR, but now that it's GPT it doesn't

Comment: I really don't think it's drive specific, it just looks like my computer can only 'see' my SSD as the only efi drive